# Fancybox Question

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Is there a way to open two pictures in one frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a Fancybox call, it resembles the following,

```
<a id="single_image" href="image_big.jpg"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

The image_small will call the image_big, and since you can only stick in one url, the answer is no.

Maybe a [photo gallery](http://galleria.aino.se/) will work better for you?